# MLFlow Models - Support/Workaround for Custom JPype Models

Tags: databricks, mlflow

I have a model that is a python object wrapper around a Java model (via JPype).

When trying to save this model via pyfunc (similar to [this](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html#custom-python-models)), I received the following error:
`TypeError: cannot pickle _jpype._JField object`

Understand that underneath the mlflow method `mlflow.pyfunc.save_model` it uses the normal pickle function, while in my case, I require the [JPickler](https://jpype.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jpype-pickle-module) class to serialize my python-wrapped Java model.

Is there a workaround in MLflow that allows me to save my "python-wrapped Java model"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work around by overriding the `load_context` method in `mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel` (to load the jar only during runtime)
https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html#example-saving-an-xgboost-model-in-mlflow-format